# Issue with adding Volley in Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-volley

I want to add `Volley` to my project in Android Studio 3.1.2. I'm trying with `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`.

and here's the Gradle for project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But it fails with the following errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details
```

and here's the image of the errors hoping giving better sense of the issue.
[image]

What I'm missing here?

Comment: It is better to post error log directly instead of an image.

Comment: @JayRathodRJ there you go. I thought maybe this way it's easier to get what's the issue.

Comment: Can you post application gradle (app.gradle) as well?

Comment: @Wizard thanks for the reply. Invalidate Caches / Restart Android Studio did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out doing `Invalidate Caches / Restart` does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with  `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`

This will definitely solve the problem.